# Picasso doesn't load image on first call ever

Tags: java, android, picasso

I have come across a very interisting issue. I am using the bellow code to load bitmaps using picasso:

```
           final Target target = new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    // loaded bitmap is here (bitmap)
                    Log.i(TAG, "bitmapLoaded");
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "bitmapFailed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            };

            imageView.setTag(target);

            Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(photoUrl)
                    .into(target);
```

I know a lot of questions have being asked about picasso not loading images due to weak reference but I don't think that's the case, since I have followed the solutions suggested in many topics to reference target like above.

In my program, I use this same code in 3 different classes and in 3 distinct moments. What I have noticed is that whenever I call this method for the first time it doesn't work, but for the next times it works, doesn't matter which of the 3 calls is being used. I can say that because I print different messages to the log from this 3 different methods.

Any thoughts about what is going on or have I missed something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to achieve this with using async approach.

```
  Picasso.with(context).load(URL).into(profile, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {//Use your "bitmap" here

                            Bitmap innerBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) profile.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    }
                }, 100);
            }
```

Also you may try to use **Glide** https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: I tried using your example but the bitmap did not loaded into the imageView, although the run() method was called.

Comment: It's the same issue, the first time I call this method it doesn't work, but the next times it does. That's odd.

Answer (score 1):

Problem: The problem is Picasso holds a weak reference to the target class and it got **GARBAGE COLLECTED**.

Solution: Convert it to class field instead of using it as local reference.

Comment: It should be the correct answer. Target is a weak reference.